# ArcPy script to set TIFF color giving ERROR 000840

Tags: arcpy, arcmap, error-000840, error-000582

I have a Python script that read csv files containing location and attributes for several objects and put all of them in a geodatabase.
I modified this script adding also a TIFF imagine with the bathymetry of the interested region using `RasterToGeodatabase_conversion`.

When I open the gdb file in ArcGIS the bathymetry is in black & white and I have to modify it manually.

What I want is to set the bathymetry map colour thought the Python script.

Looking around I discovered that I can export to a xml file template with the changes I have done manually to the bathymetry map using the button `Export raster function template...` in `Layer Propertis\Symbology`.

I tried to use this xml file in my script in this way:

```
mdname = r"D:\Projects\test_map_colour.gdb\GEBCO_Geotiff"
editmode = "EDIT_MOSAIC_DATASET"
editmethod = "INSERT"
funcfile = r"D:\Projects\Stretched.rft.xml"
funcname = "#"

arcpy.EditRasterFunction_management(mdname, editmode, editmethod, funcfile, funcname)
```

but I obtain the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 2019.1.1\helpers\pydev\_pydevd_bundle\pydevd_exec.py", line 3, in Exec
    exec exp in global_vars, local_vars
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\ArcGIS\Desktop10.6\arcpy\arcpy\geoprocessing\_base.py", line 510, in <lambda>
    return lambda *args: val(*gp_fixargs(args, True))
ExecuteError: ERROR 000582: Error occurred during execution.
```

I don't think I really understand how to use the `EditRasterFunction` function neither if this is the right way to do it...
Do you have any suggestion?

---

I tried to save the modified bathymetry map, with the color and limits I want, into a layer file (.lyr).
Opening the .lyr file in ArcMap, it keeps the settings.
Then I tried to save it into the .gdb file using ArcPy, in this way:

```
arcpy.CopyFeatures_management(r'D:\Projects\test_map.tif.lyr',
                              r'D:\Projects\test_map_colour.gdb\map')
```

but I obtain the error:

```
arcgisscripting.ExecuteError: Failed to execute. Parameters are not valid.
ERROR 000840: The value is not a Feature Layer.
ERROR 000840: The value is not a Raster Catalog Layer.
Failed to execute (CopyFeatures).
```

I also tried to export it using ArcMap with `Data\Export Data...` into the .gdb file, but I obtain the B&W imagine.

Any suggestion?
What I want is to have the colored imagine in the .gdb file, the way to obtain it is not important.

Comment: You can create a color map (http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/manage-data/raster-and-images/creating-a-color-map-clr-file.htm) then apply it to additional rasters (http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/data-management-toolbox/add-colormap.htm)

Comment: @smiller thanks for the suggestion! I am following your links, but I can't access to `Unique Values` because `The number of unique values reached the default limitaion (>65536)`. Is there another way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if this is the right solution, but I decided to create a Group Layer, set all the layer properties manually in ArcMap and save it in a .lyr file.
At the end I will have 2 files, the .gdb with the data and the .lyr with the layer properties, and not just one, but it's fine.